# Reverse the order of space separated words in a string

Tags: c#, .net

I want to split the following string on the spaces and reverse them in descending order

> 5 Damaged batten type fluorescent Luminaire sited adjacent to the Cooler in the Beer Celler C2 No

So far I have managed to split them on the spaces, however it has put them alphabetical descending order.

```
string[] lineTexts = line.Split(' ');
lineTexts =(from p in lineTexts 
            orderby p descending 
            select p).ToArray();
```

Is there any way I can reverse the whole string in descending order? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Desired output needs to be: [0]No [1]C2 [2]Celler [3]Beer [4]the [5]in [6]Cooler [7]the etc..

Comment: line.Split(' ').Reverse() should make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrderBy sorts the array alphabetically, you need Reverse.

This code example returns it back into a string reversed..

```
var line = "5 Damaged batten type fluorescent Luminaire sited adjacent to the Cooler in the Beer Celler C2 No";
string[] lineTexts = line.Split(' ').Reverse().ToArray();
Console.Write(string.Join(" ",lineTexts));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var query = line.Split()
            .OrderBy(word => word)
            .Select(word => new string(word.Reverse().ToArray()));

foreach (var w in query)
    Console.WriteLine(w);
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the OrderBy - I think he wants the order "as-is" (although the question is unclear...)

Answer (score 1):

`var result = string.Join(" ",line.Split(' ').Reverse());`